# intent is undefined tried a lot , nothing works

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, undefined

I get error with Intent. It says: `intent is undefined`. I've been searching a lot of other posts and it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

for your knowledge, i develop my own app with the basic of android developpes. Because my own intent didn't  work, i used and created the exact same class as in the example, class DisplayMessageActivity but the problem remains the same, Here some of my code.

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();


    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("fout zit hier");
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
     }
}
```

Comment: here, on SO, the tradition is to use English language and to properly format source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the first parameter on the Intent constructor.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); // wrong
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayMessageActivity.class); // right
```

The first parameter is a `Context` object, and remember that a Fragment does not inherit from `Context`, so the solution is getting the one from the parent Activity.

Comment: Zowat het enige dat ik niet geprobeerd had, de error is nu weg. Enorm hard bedankt voor het snelle antwoord

Comment: ^translation: "Just about the only thing I had not tried, the error is gone now. Very hard thanks for the quick reply"

Please use English :)

Comment: @user3450930 Graag gedaan! Kunt u de antwoord accepteren a.u.b?... Translation You're welcome.

Comment: Even better - never start an `Activity` from a `Fragment`. A `Fragment` should be self-contained and reusable and as such should never know about other application components. The `Fragment` should use a callback interface to tell the parent `Activity` to start the other `Activity` instead.

Comment: @Squonk not in any situation I guess? For example I have a `ListFragment` displaying the list of files in its `ListView` and launch a broadcast `Intent` on an item click. I use `getActivity()` as the `Context`, since I know this `Fragment` won't be reused.. am I wrong at this point?

Comment: @Droidman : If you want to use that approach for developing code then that is your choice. If you know you're never going to reuse that `Fragment` code in any other situation then that's fine but you're breaking the concept of reusable code and, in essence, the whole idea of the `Fragment` class. Ideally an `Activity` which uses `Fragments` should "know" everything about them but no `Fragment` should ever rely on how they are being used. If you want to use that approach then just putt all of your code into a `ListActivity` and forget about `Fragments`.

Comment: I just used the interface i got when i started the project. Now after deleting the fragment shizzle. All my other problems are gone. I, now, have a good working app, as what i expected from it. I all thank you a lot for your answers. Android developping is getting clearer and clearer to me. Have a good night